# Velocity.js - How to use sequences with UI effects?

Tags: javascript, jquery, velocity.js

I'm trying with no success so far.

We can have something like this:

```
 function _nextStepTransition(elementOut, elementIn) {

        var goForward = [
            { e: elementOut, p: { translateX: 100 }, o: { duration: 1000 } },
            { e: elementIn, p: { translateX: 200 }, o: { duration: 1000 } }
        ];
        $.Velocity.RunSequence(goForward);
    }
```

As far as I understood, p stands for property. Ok.

Does anyone know if we can pass as `p:` *property*, the UI effect `transition.slideDownBigIn`, so that we can have a sequence of UI effects?

I'm clueless about the syntax to apply here (if possible), and my tries result in nothing so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, of course. Simply replace the `Object` in `p` with a `string` of the transition/callout you wish to make, as in:

```
var goForward = [
        { e: elementOut, p: 'callout.pulse', o: { duration: 1000 } },
        { e: elementIn, p: 'transition.flipXIn', o: { duration: 1000 } }
    ];
```

See an [example here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MawwJe).

Comment: Care to share where did you find that info? Is there on documentation, or somewhere else? Thank you. I was not removing the `{` hence, the constant syntax errors we were having.

Comment: I think it's not covered in the docs. I officially do user support on the project's repo and you're welcome to open an issue to add this to the docs.